# Convert yyyymmdd string to Date class in R

Tags: r, class, date

I would like to convert these dates with format YYYYMMDD to a Date class.

```
dates <- data.frame(Date = c("20130707", "20130706", "20130705", "20130704"))
```

I tried:

```
dates <- as.Date(dates, "%Y%m%d")
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in as.Date.default(dates, "%Y%m%d") : 
  do not know how to convert 'dates' to class "Date"
```

What would be the correct way to set this format?

Answer (score 27):

You need to provide the `Date` column, not the entire `data.frame`.

```
R> as.Date(dates[["Date"]], "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2013-07-07" "2013-07-06" "2013-07-05" "2013-07-04"
```

Comment: And what if we don't want the dashes (`-`)

Comment: That's what OP started with.  Dates are printed with hyphens in R.  If you don't want them, you can either make your own print method (probably not what you're after), or convert them to character: `format(myDates, "%Y%m%d")`.

Answer (score 16):

An extra conversion to characters works for me:

```
dates<-as.Date(as.character(dates),format="%Y%m%d")
```

Without the conversion the following error occurs:

```
dates<-as.Date(dates,format="%Y%m%d")
Error in as.Date.numeric(dates, format = "%Y%m%d") : 
  'origin' must be supplied
```

Different error but this might help, works for POSIXct too, paste date and hours, format %Y%m%d%H

Answer (score 9):

Classic R:

```
> start_numeric <- as.Date('20170215', format = '%Y%m%d');
> start_numeric
[1] "2017-02-15"
> format(start_numeric, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "20170215"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the lubridate package for an easy conversion:

```
date_test <- data.frame(Date = c("20130707", "20130706", "20130705", "20130704"))
date_test$Date <- ymd(date_test$Date)

date_test
        Date
1 2013-07-07
2 2013-07-06
3 2013-07-05
4 2013-07-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using brackets, you can use variable name:

```
dates <- data.frame(Date = c("20130707", "20130706", "20130705", "20130704"))
as.Date(dates$Date, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2013-07-07" "2013-07-06" "2013-07-05" "2013-07-04"
```