# Split numeric yyyymmdd column

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe containing a DATE column which I reference as NM_DATA$DATE. It is a numeric in the form of yyyymmdd, I know, a hundred threads on this...

I tried every solution I could find and they won't work for me. About to reload RStudio.

```
NM_DATA$DATES <- as.Date(NM_DATA$DATES, "%Y%m%d")
```

returns

> Error in as.Date.default(NM_DATA$DATES, "%Y%m%d") :  do not know how
> to convert 'NM_DATA$DATES' to class "Date"

Can someone please explain how to get DATE column:

```
DATE
19870401
19870501
etc
```

into:

```
DATE
1987-04
1987-05
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should clarify that I will be averaging yearly data but would like to be able to reference monthly patterns in the future.... that is why I would like to split for now but keep the month in this data set

Comment: `library(lubridqte); year(ymd(NM_DATA$DATE))`? Can you be more specific about the error?

Comment: NM_DATA$DATE <- library(lubridate); year(ymd(NM_DATA$DATE))   all formats failed to parse, no formats found...    library(lubridate); year(ymd(NM_DATA$DATE))  returned years in the console that looked correct....

Comment: In your hours of search, did you come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518564/format-date-in-r-yyyymmdd) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116388/r-read-dates-in-format-yyyymmdd)? :)

Comment: yes and yes.... cant get either to work...

Comment: Error in as.Date.default(NM_DATA$DATES, "%Y%M%D") : 
  do not know how to convert 'NM_DATA$DATES' to class "Date"   when i use  NM_DATA$DATES <- as.Date(NM_DATA$DATES, "%Y%M%D")  oops... fixed %M%D to %m%d... still same error

Comment: @jbaums your second example shows the same solution as here, except the question itself is not worded very well. The example provided here presents the question in a more understandable way, imo.

Answer (score 6):

In the interest of having a complete answer here, I'm fleshing out @Alex's answer somewhat.

The `as.Date` function can be used to convert a character string (or vector thereof) to `Date` format. The help page for `strptime` (`?strptime`) gives some valuable information about possible formats that `Date` objects can use.

In your case, you want to convert the `NM_DATA$DATE` vector to dates. The format yyyymmdd is represented by `%Y%m%d`, thus if your vector is character, we can convert it like so:

```
NM_DATA$DATE <- as.Date(NM_DATA$DATE, format='%Y%m%d')
```

However, if it is numeric (instead of character), we first need to coerce to character to avoid an `'origin' must be supplied` error. (You could check the mode of the vector with `mode(NM_DATA$DATE)`.)

```
NM_DATA$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(NM_DATA$DATE), format='%Y%m%d')
```

Now that the vector is a `Date` object, we can format it in various ways (outlined at `?strptime`). To extract year, month and day numbers:

```
NM_DATA$YEAR <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%Y')
NM_DATA$MONTH <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%m')
NM_DATA$DAY <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%d')
```

If you want month name, instead, you can use `%B` (or `%b`, for abbreviated month names), e.g.:

```
NM_DATA$MONTHNAME <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%B')
```

Comment: I tried NM_DATA$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(NM_DATA$DATE), format='%Y%m%d')  however I only get a 4 digit character in the DATE column...

Comment: Then there must be some peculiarities about your `DATE` column... not all elements are `yyyymmdd`. Do some elements only have a year, rather than the full date? This would also explain your error `do not know how to convert 'NM_DATA$DATES' to class "Date"`, and changes the question completely, from one of "how do I convert yyyymmdd to a Date object", to "how do I convert a vector of mixed date formats to a Date object". The answer to the latter is that you  need to make them consistent first, by converting to character and performing string manipulations.

Comment: it is 145.208 rows long.... I am 90% sure they are all formatted yyyymmdd... I am going to bed. Will try again tomorrow.  thanks again for all your help

Comment: Try `unique(nchar(NM_DATA$DATES))` or `NM_DATA$DATES[which(nchar(NM_DATA$DATES) != 8)]`

Answer (score 3):

Use the format option with the right syntax to process the 8 digits:

```
as.Date("20130408",format="%Y%m%d")
```

Then, use the the `format()` command to extract what you want, see
[Extract month and year from a zoo::yearmon object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749598/r-obtaining-month-and-year-from-a-date)

Comment: unexpected string constant in NM_DATA$DATE <- as.Date(NM_DATA$DATE, "20130408", format "%Y%m%d")   also tried   as.Date( "20130408", format "%Y%m%d")  to print to console and no luck... same error

Comment: @user1680636: More specifically, try `NM_DATA$DATE <- as.Date(NM_DATA$DATE, format='%Y%m%d')`. Then, to split into components: `NM_DATA$MONTH <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%m')` and `NM_DATA$DAY <- format(NM_DATA$DATE, '%d')`. Take a look at `?strptime` for other possible formats, e.g. `%b` for abbreviated month name.

Comment: origin must be supplied... tried origin = "1970-01-01" returns error unexpected symbol

Comment: You are missing equals signs in your code posted here as comments... `format='%Y%m%d'`.

Comment: This method is the way to go and works as described if the data is a character vector, e.g.: `test <- "19870401"; format(as.Date(test,"%Y%m%d"),"%Y-%m")` Try breaking your issue down to a simple example that works and then find where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try substr according to your request.

```
YEAR<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(NM_DATA$DATE),1,4))
MONTH<-as.numeric(substr(as.numeric(NM_DATA$DATE),5,6))
```

I agree @Alex answer is more elegant.

Comment: This will work... Thank you very much... still confused about the date issue though.

Comment: @Yln, I updated my question to be clearer, I may still have to go this route though... Thanks again.

Comment: This is what you want probably: substr(as.Date(NM_DATA$DATE,format="%Y%m%d"),1,7)

Comment: Or, I guess `read.fwf(file=textConnection(as.character(NM_DATA$DATE)), widths = c(4, 2, 2), col.names=c("YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY"), colClasses = "character")`...