# Merging two data frames by dates that have different types

Tags: r, date, merge

I have two data frames with date variables. The first data frame's date variable is type "Date" in YYYY-MM-DD format.  The second data frame's date variable is type "integer" in YYYYMMDD format.  I am trying to convert one, or both, date variables so I can merge the two data frames by each data frame's date variable.  I realize this is a multi-step process, but I'm having difficulty with creating / converting to do the merge.

The first data frame has the following code:
FF$FFReportDT<-(strptime(FF$Month,format="%Y-%m-%d")), the conversion of a YYYY-MM-DD formatted "Date" variable type to a POSIXLt variable type.

The second data frame has the following code:

```
  lsHFIndex$FFReportDt <- strptime(lsHFIndex$ReportDt,"%Y%m%d")
```

....., the conversion of a YYYYMMDD formatted "Integer" variable type to a POSIXLt variable type.

When I do the merge with the following code:

```
lsHFIndexFF<-merge(lsHFIndex, FF, by.x="FFReportDt", by.y="FFReportDt")
```

I get the following error message:
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Problem is when I look at each data frame's 'FFReportDt' variable, each looks good.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776381/splitting-numeric-yyyymmdd-column-r/22776723#22776723

Comment: Convert to Date class first. (And pkg:lubridate has some coercion functions that are "smart" in that their authors tried to put in code that makes "educated" guesses at formatting.

Comment: The first data frame variable FF$Month is a Date, but the second data frame variable lsHFIndex$ReportDt is an Integer. I thought the strptime() operation created the same class variable - a POSIXlt variable, on which I could merge the two data frames.  What am I doing wrong with that approach?  Thanks @BondedDust for the lubridate suggestion, by the way.  I will have to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust! The lubridate package and the ymd function worked wonders. Appreciate all the attention.